# My question was voted as off-topic even though it was about programming

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked a question about finding sound card on Linux. I wanted to do it programmatically using code.

The question has been voted as off-topic, while I really think it's not. How can I reopen to add the answer I found ?

Question:
[Finding available sound cards on Linux programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288782/finding-availble-sound-cards-on-linux-programmatically)

Comment: I also voted to re-open. But why did it take you 9 months?

Comment: Yes I decided to answer my question. I actually wasn't that experienced with stackoverflow and didn't know I can reopen the question.

Comment: I agree, should not have been closed. At this moment, it only needs one more reopen vote -- I suspect the power of meta will deliver the last one soon!

Comment: Thanks everyone. The question has been reopened.